# 2 apache vhosts permanent redirect

Tags: apache, redirect

I have 2 domains which I have separately configured in 2 vhosts files. I need one of this domains to permanently redirect to the second one. Before reloading apache, I've run 'configtest' and I got "Syntax Ok". However apparently I got a redirect loop. Btw, the website is a drupal installation, not sure how much does this count.

Here's my 2 conf files.

```
[root@prod ~]# cat meh-1_com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName meh-1.com
    ServerAlias www.meh-1.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/meh1/

    <Directory /var/www/html/meh1/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/meh1.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName meh-1.com
    ServerAlias www.meh-1.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/meh1/

    <Directory /var/www/html/meh1/>
                Options +FollowSymLinks Indexes
                AllowOverride All
                order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>    

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/meh1.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/httpd/ssl/meh1_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/httpd/ssl/meh1_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/meh1_com.ca-bundle.crt
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>

[root@prod ~]# cat meh-2_com.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName meh-2.com
    ServerAlias www.meh-2.com
    Redirect permanent / http://meh-1.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName meh-2.com
        ServerAlias www.meh-2.com
        Redirect permanent / https://meh-1.com

</VirtualHost>
```